# why query selector not working for second class

Tags: html, css

I have many css class how to work that all

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="B3">sgddsg</div>
<div class="B5">dsgdsg</div>
<script>
var nam = document.querySelector('.B3,.B5');
nam.style.width = '100px';
nam.style.height = '100px';
nam.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
nam.style.color = 'white';

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here class B3 is working but B5 not why any solution in one line code.

Comment: "I have many css class" — Those are HTML classes not CSS classes. CSS doesn't have classes, only class selectors.

Comment: Can you post one of your css? because as Quentin said, css doesn't have classess

Comment: @Alpha_Wing — The CSS (other than the manipulations in the JS which we can see in the question) is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: actually i deteted the the href line from head which i havent included , that have css classes in css file.

Comment: @avinashmajhi — There is still no such thing as a CSS class. You might mean a class selector. You might mean a rule-set. Classes are an HTML thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`querySelector` only returns the first matching element.

If you want to match more than one element, you'll need to use `querySelectorAll`, then iterate over the results:

```js
var nam = document.querySelectorAll('.B3,.B5');

for (var i = 0; i < nam.length; i++) {
  var elem = nam[i];
  elem.style.width = '100px';
  elem.style.height = '100px';
  elem.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  elem.style.color = 'white';
};
```

```html
<div class="B3">sgddsg</div>
<div class="B5">dsgdsg</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

`querySelector` returns the **first** element that matches the selector. If you want to return **all** the elements then you need [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

`querySelectorAll` doesn't return a *single* element though, so you'll [need to deal with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method).